# typescript: How to annotate a type that's a class (instead of a class instance)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, typescript

Let's assume there is a model class like:

```
export abstract class Target {
    id!: number;
    name!: string;
}

export class Target1 extends Target {
    name = 'target1';
    id: number;
    kind: string;

    constructor(id: number, kind: string) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.kind = kind;
    }
 
    static getForm(){
      return new FormGroup({...});
    }
}

export class Target2 extends Target {
    name = 'target2';
    id: number;
    address: string;

    constructor(id: number, address: string) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.address = address;
    }

    static getForm(){
       return new FormGroup({...});
    }
}

....
export class TargetN extends Target {}

type Measure = {
    type: string;
    target: any; // Here is what I need to correct the type
}

const measures: Measure[] = [
    { type: 'measure1', target: Target1},
    { type: 'measure2', target: Target2},
    ...
    { type: 'measureN', target: TargetN},
];
```

In the form, I allow user input `address` or `kind` based on situation user selected `measures.type` then I will instance a new `target` as bellow:

```
const inputValue = 'http://localhost:3000';
const selectedType = measures[0].type;
const measure = measures.find(m => m.type === selectedType)!;
const target = new measure.target(1, inputValue);
const form = measure.target.getForm();
console.log(target.kind); // 
...
```

Everything is working fine. But which annoys me is that I don't know how to put the correct type at `Measure -> target` instead of `any`:

```
type Measure = {
    type: string;
    target: any; // ??? 
}
```

If I give it a type `Target` like bellow:

```
type Measure = {
    type: string;
    target: Target;
}
```

then I will get the error

```js
 Did you mean to use 'new' with this expression?
```

And, if I give it `typeof` like bellow:

```
type Measure = {
    type: string;
    target: typeof Target;
}
```

then I will get the error

```js
 Type 'typeof Target1' is not assignable to type 'typeof Target'.
```

How can I replace type `any` in target with another specificity type?

If I use [ThisType](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#thistypetype) it looks good

```
type Measure = {
    type: string;
    target: ThisType<Target>;
}
```

but the `static method` inside `Target1 or Target2` it will throw error

```js
Property 'getForm' does not exist on type 'ThisType<Target>'.
```

I also tried with [Required](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#requiredtype) like below:

```
type RequiredTarget = Required<typeof Target>;
type Measure = {
    type: string;
    target: RequiredTarget;
}
```

but it's not working too.

I appreciate your help with that.

Comment: Have you tried... 

target: TypeA | TypeB | TypeC | undefined;  

construct?

Comment: No, I can't. It'll throw the error: `Did you mean to use 'new' with this expression?`

Comment: `typeof Target`

Comment: @kaya3 it throws an error `Type 'typeof Target1' is not assignable to type 'typeof Target'.`

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this with the following manner:

```
    type S = string;
    type I = number;

    interface IY {
        type?: string;
        target?: S | I;
    }

    type Y = IY

    const U: Y = { type: "U", target: "1" }
    const V: Y = { type: "V", target: 2 }
    const X: Y = {}
```

Comment: Hi https://stackoverflow.com/users/4744055/manabu-tokunaga, in my case it will throw an error: `Did you mean to use 'new' with this expression?`